Display different product description per product variation in Woocommerce
I'm going crazy. What I want to do is to create a listing per design and have "variation" on what material they want it to print.
For example: Design is "Spiderman" and under variation they can select whether to print in: Sintra Board, A3 Poster, Metal etc.
I want to display a different description based on their selected material (different specs for sintra, a3,metal) and for it to appear on the MAIN PRODUCT Description instead of as a short description under the variation.
If you can check castify's website, once you select a case type the description below changes as well.
Is this possible with a plugin? I hope someone can help me!
I have no coding experience but I've tried a bunch of plugins and none of them worked

I dont think there is plugin but using js you can listen what variation is selected and grab that description and put it w/e you want.

Try this code in Dashboard > Appearance > Edit Theme File > Functions.php and paste the below snippet.
// Add custom JavaScript to the product page
    function custom_variation_description_script() {
        // Check if we're on a single product page
        if (is_product()) {
            global $product;
            // Check if the product has variations
            if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
                ?>
                <script>
                    jQuery(function($){
                        // When a variation is changed
                        $('form.variations_form').on('change', '.variation-select', function(){
                            // Get the selected variation description
                            var variationDescription = $(this).find('option:selected').data('variation-description');
                            // Update the product description with the variation description
                            $('.woocommerce-product-details__short-description').html(variationDescription);
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_variation_description_script');
    
    // Add custom variation description data to each product variation
    function custom_variation_description($variations) {
        // Loop through each variation
        foreach ($variations as $variation) {
            // Get the variation ID
            $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
            // Get the variation object
            $product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
            // Get the custom description for this variation (replace 'variation_description' with your custom field name)
            $variation_description = get_post_meta($variation_id, 'variation_description', true);
            // Add the custom description to the variation data
            $variation['variation_description'] = $variation_description;
        }
        return $variations;
    }
    add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_variation_description');


I used this but got this error. Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_type() on string in /home/.../public_html/wp-content/themes/woodmart-child/functions.php on line 128 - line 128: if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
